# Unsupported virtual sd card in android emulator

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, android-sdcard

I don't know why the virtual SD card isn't working anymore. Someone got any leads or why could that happen?

I'm using Android emulator with API 26 (Android O)

[image: Screenshot 1]
[image: Screenshot 2]

Comment: did you get any solution yet? i got the same problem and after reformat multiple times, still not working

Comment: No, not yet. I used API 24 system image instead.

Answer (score 2):

To solve this problem use sd card size >= 512 MB in emulator . Android studio 2.3.3 created 100 MB sd card by default.

The commit on the AOSP source code for Android Oreo states that a 512-megabyte file is created and mounted as a virtual disk for the system to use as an SD card.

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same problem too. Like others have mentioned, AVDs which have SD cards that are less than 512 MB do not detect the card after the upgrade to Android Studio 3. I did the following:

1. Stop the AVD if its running
2. Open AVD manager and edit the properties for the AVD. Ensure that the SD card is 512 MB or more
3. Restart the AVD.

Your emulator should be able to detect the card now.

Answer (score 0):

I set up a new device using API 24 and it the SD card worked perfectly fine. I believe this is because API 26 is new and virtual SD card support is not available yet on emulator.