# Corrupted Virtual SD card error in Android Studio 2.3.3 on macOS Sierra

Tags: android, macos, android-emulator, android-sdcard

Installed Android Studio 2.3.3 on macOS Sierra (version 10.12.6).
Created template login application, and created Nexus 5X API 26 virtual device. When I run the application, the emulator starts but gives following error:

```
Corrupted Virtual SD card
Virtual SD card corrupted. Tap to fix.
```

Double click on the message and "Set up your Virtual SD card" screen is displayed.

Selected "Use as portable storage" option and clicked "Erase and Format" button on the next screen.

System displays "Command 17... format error..." and disappears and application does not run.

How an I fix this please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Created new device to support API level 24 as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45788160/unsupported-virtual-sd-card-in-android-emulator)
No SD Card error any more!